# Invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python

I am trying to compute implied volatility of black scholes formula using python. however, I have problem with my code. I keep getting this error message when I running the code:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
v = sigmaOld - bs_option_call(v, s, k, r, t, call_price1)/fprime(sigmaOld, s, k, r, t)e here
```

and here is my code:

```
while True:
for (v, k, s, t, call_price1) in zip(sigma, K, S, Ta, call_price_list):
    sigmaOld = v
    v = sigmaOld - bs_option_call(v, s, k, r, t, call_price1) / fprime(sigmaOld, s, k, r, t)
    if scipy.absolute( v - sigmaOld ) < epsilon:
        break
print(sigma)
```

where `fprime` is

```
def fprime(sigma, S, K, r, T):
    logSoverK = log(S / K)
    numerd1 = logSoverK + (r + sigma**2 / 2) * T
    d1 = numerd1 / (sigma*sqrt(T))
    return S * sqrt(T) * norm.pdf(d1) * exp(-r * T)
```

and K, Ta, S, sigma, call_price_list are lists and r is just a number.

I tried to use

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
```

but it was not useful for me for some reason!

can anyone please have a look at my code and tell me what is my mistake!
Many thanks in advance

Comment: I guess `fprime()` returns zero(es?). What is `fprime()` code? Also, what are values of `sigmaOld`, `s`, `k`, `r` and `t` when the error occurs? Which python version do you use?

Comment: I edited my question above to answer yours. thanks.

Comment: "just a number" - `float`, `int` or `numpy.array`? also, where `log` and `sqrt` are imported from? The Python version may be important too.

Comment: float and I imported log and sqrt from from scipy. I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Printing errors and warnings to stderr is default Python functionality.

You're getting this warning because you're dividing by zero i.e. the `fprime` is returning zero.

---

If you want to suppress the warning using [`warning filters`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter):

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore')
```

It'll tell Numpy to ignore the divide by zero warning - all the allowed parameters for [`seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).

Comment: what you didn't get ? the warning is because fprime is returning 0, and you're dividing return of bs_option_call by 0 - above I have shared a way to suppress this warning, if you're concerned if fprime is really returning 0, have a print in fprime jjust before the return statement.